# Access has_one through value before record is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models, `TicketOrder`, `User`, and `Order`

An `Order` `has_one :user` and a `TicketOrder` `belongs_to :order`.

A `TicketOrder` `has_one :user, through: :order`

When creating a new `Order` I am also doing `@order.ticket_orders.new` to create a new `TicketOrder`. Before my `TicketOrder` is saved I want to validate something regarding the `User`. The problem is:

```
> @order = Order.new(user: User.first)
> @ticket_order = @order.ticket_orders.new
> @ticket_order.user
=> nil
```

Is there something wrong with the way my models are set up that is preventing me from accessing `@ticket_order.user`?

Comment: Does the `Order` has `has_many :ticket_orders`?

Comment: Yes, it does have that.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the output when you enter each line of code into the rails console ("rails c -s")?